# Differentiate requests from accounts all currently logged in from the same computer?

Tags: express, meanjs

If I log in Acc1, then open a private browsing session in a browser to log in Acc2, then all requests sent will have "user" field as Acc1 and data stored will have owner ID as Acc1 instead of Acc2.

What should I do in order to differentiate requests coming from Acc1 and Acc2 with ExpressJS?

Comment: All requests are unique in express. I think you want to check session info, to do that you need a session store. Store what ever data you need in that and check